# How do I go about finding the double integral in first quadrant, given $y=x^2$ and $y=x^3$?

Tags: calculus, integration

"$$\iint_{R} 2xy\, dA$$ where $R$ is the limited area in the first quadrant between the graphs $y = x^2$ and $y = x^3$"

How do I find the $R$ values I'm lacking from the given information? I understand I should somehow use these y values to find the rest of the $R$, but I have no idea how, and would appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Suppose this was a question in first year calculus, find the area of region R.  What does this integral look like?  This will hopefully give you some insight into the bounds for R in this double integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have $x^3\le y\le x^2$ then the only points in which the bounding graphs intersect are when $x^3=x^2\implies x=0,1$. So the bounds for $x$ must be $0\le x\le1$ in order for a finite region to be bounded. So, the integral is given by
$$\int\int_R 2xy dA=\int_0^1\int_{x^3}^{x^2}2xydydx$$

Then the integral is equal to
$$\int_0^1\int_{x^3}^{x^2}2xydydx=\int_0^1x\cdot[y^2]_{x^3}^{x^2}dx=\int_0^1x^5-x^7dx=[\frac16x^6-\frac18x^8]_0^1=\frac1{24}$$